# Multiple user logins on a development server using Django

Tags: django, python-3.3

I was wondering whether it is possible to have more than one user log in on a development server using Django 1.8

I am creating an app, where these "active" users are able to view one another details (or fields) respective to the relative models I designed.

Currently, I am only able to log in as a single user and wondered whether it is possible to somehow allow my app to have multiple logins.

Thanks

Comment: The server doesn't make any difference. How exactly are you trying to log in as multiple users, and what exactly happens when you do that?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use multiple browsers, and if necessary, multiple dev servers on alternate ports. 8000, 8001, etc.